# How to link python file with the html file

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've started one new django project. I've linked the HTML file in the django's admin page. When I click view site in the admin page the html file has open.

In this html file there is a register button. When I click it, the html form will open for fill the details to register for signup.

When I filled the details and click submit button, the python file (signup.py) has to show the data and save in db. But I got the error

"**Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.95.228.84:8000/signup.py?CID=aasa&user_name=sadsad&User_email=sasa%40gmail.com&DOB1=2016-08-30&Password11=sasasa&Password12=sasasa&submit=submit**"

Please let me know how to link this signup.py file with this html.

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of django and how it operates. I'd suggest looking for some tutorials on how to get started and how to structure your apps, views, templates, etc. I'll post some links later (unless someone else beats me to it)

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is that you have a GET request to a URL that happens to be named 'signup.py' followed by the form parameters. This is not how Django fundamentally operates. Django forms automatically 'takes care of' saving new entries into the database if the forms are valid (assuming you are using a correct model and ModelForms).

I can't tell what your models are like or your urls, but I would suggest:
1) Creating Models in models.py that accurately match what you are trying to save into your database (if you haven't already)
2) Creating a view in views.py and that will link to a template (that you will need to create) displaying the data that is being saved into your database
3) Creating a url for this new view you created in urls.py
4) Editing the view that is currently handling the signup form to redirect your your view if the form is valid.

I would suggest looking at the Django tutorial. Going through it once or twice will solidify the basic workflow of using Django. This tutorial also has a solid tutorial on simple forms.

[Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)

[Simple Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial04/)